# How would I apply an object into a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that my sidenav, when clicked, displays the corresponding values that the element has inside the array that is initialized inside my javascript file.

Here is my HTML

A shortened version of my html but has recurring elements that have the same class, no id and the same wrapper but named differently

```
<div class="infernum" id="Infernum">
        <div class="dragon-push">Infernum</div>
        <div class="text-push"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="sprite">
        <div class="dragon-push">Sprite</div>
        <div class="text-push"></div>
      </div>
```

And my JS Logic is this:

```
document.getElementById("Infernum").addEventListener("click", function(){
  const target = this.id;
  console.log(target);
  getSome(dragonArray, target);
})

function getSome(arr, id){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++ ){
    if (id === arr[i].name){
      const dragonsName = dragonArray.find(obj => obj.name === id);
      console.log(dragonsName);
    }
  }
}
```

I am attempting to place the contents of the object in this div:

```
      <div class="dragons">
        <div class="dragon-name">no*</div>
        <div class="element">el*</div>
        <div class="habitat">ha*</div>
        <div class="age">age*</div>
        <div class="text">te*</div>
      </div>
```

And an example of one of my objects:

```
const infernum =
{
  name: "Infernum",
  element: "Fire",
  habitat: "The Scorching Caldera",
  age: 7258,
  text: "asda"
}
```

I've tried to access the individual objects and add event listeners for each click but it gives back undefined

Comment: You don't need both the `for` loop and `dragonArray.find()`. They're both looking for the same thing. Just use `arr.find()`.

Comment: Once you get the array element, use `document.querySelector(".dragon-name").innerText = dragonsName.name;` And similar for the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's break down the changes you need in order for your code to work

First of all (as user @Barmar has said in the comments), you don't need both `for` loop and `dragonArray.find()` as they search for the same thing. You could do something like

```
  function getSome(arr, id) {
        const dragon = arr.find((obj) => obj.name === id);
                if (dragon) {
                     ...
```

Then, you need to store the values you want inside the elements. The final getSome function would look something like

```
  function getSome(arr, id) {
    const dragon = arr.find((obj) => obj.name === id);
    if (dragon) {
      // You need to store the values in the elements
      document.querySelector(".dragon-name").innerText = dragon.name;
      document.querySelector(".element").innerText = dragon.element;
      document.querySelector(".habitat").innerText = dragon.habitat;
      document.querySelector(".age").innerText = dragon.age;
      document.querySelector(".text").innerText = dragon.text;
    }
  }
```

Then, for the Event Listeners, Instead of adding individual event listeners to each dragon by its ID, you can loop through them using their class, such as

```
  document.querySelectorAll(".dragon-push").forEach((dragonDiv) => {
    dragonDiv.parentElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
      const target = dragonDiv.textContent;
      getSome(dragonArray, target);
    });
  });
```

To showcase a live example, look at the code snipped below. If you have any doubts, I will be happy to answer them below in the comments :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dragon Details</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="infernum" id="Infernum">
      <div class="dragon-push">Infernum</div>
      <div class="text-push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite">
      <div class="dragon-push">Foo</div>
      <div class="text-push"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="dragons">
      <div class="dragon-name">no*</div>
      <div class="element">el*</div>
      <div class="habitat">ha*</div>
      <div class="age">age*</div>
      <div class="text">te*</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Example Data
      const dragonArray = [
        {
          name: "Infernum",
          element: "Fire",
          habitat: "The Scorching Caldera",
          age: 7258,
          text: "asda",
        },
        {
          name: "Foo",
          element: "Water",
          habitat: "Bar",
          age: 41,
          text: "FooBar",
        },
      ];

      // Function to display dragon details
      function getSome(arr, id) {
        const dragon = arr.find((obj) => obj.name === id);
        if (dragon) {
          // You need to store the values in the elements
          document.querySelector(".dragon-name").innerText = dragon.name;
          document.querySelector(".element").innerText = dragon.element;
          document.querySelector(".habitat").innerText = dragon.habitat;
          document.querySelector(".age").innerText = dragon.age;
          document.querySelector(".text").innerText = dragon.text;
        }
      }

      // Add click event to each dragon
      document.querySelectorAll(".dragon-push").forEach((dragonDiv) => {
        dragonDiv.parentElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
          const target = dragonDiv.textContent;
          getSome(dragonArray, target);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```